# Java - ignoring certain characters while reading a text file

Tags: java, input, io, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a simple text file that contains the following:

LOAD

Bill's Beans

1200

20

15

30

QUIT

I need to store and print the contents line by line. I am doing so using the following code:

```
    String inputFile = "(file path here)";
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String currentLine = "";
    while (!currentLine.equals("QUIT}")){
        currentLine = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(currentLine);
    }
    input.close();
```

However, the output is very "messy". I am trying to avoid storing all new line characters and anything else that doesn't appear in the text file. Output is:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540

{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}

{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}

\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0

\deftab720

\pard\pardeftab720\ql\qnatural

\f0\fs26 \cf0 LOAD\

Bill's Beans\

1200\

20\

15\

30\

QUIT}

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks like it's more than a simple text file?

Comment: That's not a text file, that's a rtf file. Open the file in Notepad or your OS's equivalent.

Comment: Did you look into using an RTF parser to get the text?

Comment: Note: System.out.println(currentLine); is adding the newline characters. Use  System.out.print(currentLine); instead.

Comment: So your input file is some JSON feed or something?  Where are those {} things coming from?  I think your input text file is not as simple as you may think.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you're reading a RTF file, isn't that so, by any chance?

Otherwise, I found reading text files is most natural for me using this construct:

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new FileReader(new File("yourfile.txt")
                                );
        String text = null;

        // repeat until all lines is read
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do whatever with the text line
        }
```

Because this is an RTF file, look into this for example:  [RTFEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html)

Comment: It actually is an RTF and my program is on a Mac. But the program will ultimately be ran on a Windows machine with a text file. When I use the buffered reader I get the exact same results. When it is ran on a Windows machine with a text file, will those special characters be ignored?

Comment: That doesn't matter that much. Problem is, you're trying to read a proprietary format with a structure. So the special characters won't be ignored, if you do it this way. Look into RTFEditorKit for example. I added a link to the answer to get you started. But bear in mind, you have to parse the file somehow, because it's not plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on writing your own RTF reader, the correct approach would be for you to extend  [FilterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and handle the RTF metadata in its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code into your class, then call it with path parameter. it returns all lines as List object

```
public List<String> readStudentsNoFromText(String path) throws IOException {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Print the content on the console
                System.out.println(strLine);
                result.add(strLine.trim());

            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();

            return result;
        }
```